# Visual Studio 2017 xunit test working directory

Tags: testing, xunit, visual-studio-2017

When I run my `xunit` tests from VS 2017 the working directory is different than it was in VS 2015 and what's even more ugly - it's different for just executing a test and debugging one.

In execute mode its like `UnitTestProject\bin\debug\netcoreapp1.1`

In debug - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\`

When I run `dotnet test` from within my project folder it's just `UnitTestProject`

I prefer the latter and that's actually how it was in VS 2015 - it was always project directory in all three cases.

So the question is how to make VS 2017 (and `dotnet test` unless there's a new way now) to use the same working dir.

Comment: Not an answer, but related info: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/978

Comment: There is an open issue on this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/311. If you look at the las comment it seems that this will be updated with VS 2017 update 1. Best.

Comment: @jtkech I think you should post your comment as answer. e.g. "currently you can't do that, but there is an open issue etc....". Even though such an answer is hopefully temporary (till the issue is fixed), it's still a legitimate (and correct) answer. You can always revisit your answer when the issue is fixed.